# How do I display the start date and end date of certain date in recurrance calendar item?

Tags: recurring-events

I have created a calendar and have added a repeating event. However, when I click on a certain date within the repeating events, the start date is showed as the start date of the series of recurrence event and the end date is showed as the end date of the series of events. I noticed that when I click on a certain date and edit the event, it "breaks" the event and the start date and end date shows up correctly. I'm just wondering if anyone knows of a way to do it through workflow or something to "break" the repeating event so that the start date and end date would show up correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Recurrence in SharePoint is pretty complex and (IMHO) pretty strangely implemented, although it was likely done this way for compatibility with Exchange/Outlook.

When you create a recurrence event, it is stored as a single record even if you have multiple occurrences. Internally, the start/end dates match the start/end of the range as you said, and there is an XML snippet stored with the item that defines the recurrence (for example "Every Sunday for 20 weeks"). If you put no end date (unlimited range), the stored End Date will be somewhere in the year 2040.

The calendar shows multiple occurrences because it is *expanding* the single record into multiple ones. You will notice if you click on one, that its ID is a bit weird with a decimal part but that does not correspond to an item in the DB.

When you edit one of those expanded "virtual" items, SharePoint creates a new actual item with a recurrence status of "Exception" or "Deleted" (when you delete a date in the series).

So "Breaking" the recurring event amounts to inserting exceptions or deletions. If you want to do it for the whole series, you might as well use multiple single-items and link them somehow in a different manner. I've tried to do this in a past project, where we needed more complex recurrence rules, and it more or less worked / is quite a pain to manage properly.

See [this blog post](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blog/Pages/BlogPost.aspx?PageType=4&ListId=%7B72C1C85B-1D2D-4A4A-90DE-CA74A7808184%7D&pID=761) from the SharePoint Team blog for more details on the schema.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you clicking on the event?

If it's in the calendard where the link is like this

> http://sp2010/Lists/MyCal/DispForm.aspx?ID=3.0.2012-04-12T10:00:00Z

then it should show up correctly.

If the link is like this

> http://sp2010/Lists/MyCal/DispForm.aspx?ID=3

it'll show up "corrupted"

Comment: I am clicking it from the weekly calendar view and I'm using @EventDate to display the date.